# testing an isbn number to see if its valid

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am having trouble with a homework assignment where I need to check if the ISBN code is valid. This is a beginner C++ class, and I am new to all of this. Right now, no matter what ISBN I put in, it tells me they are all valid. If someone could help point me in the right direction to figure out if my formula is correct when in my for() statement.

I have no problem with the outside loops, it's just the conversion I believe I am doing wrong.

being this is an intro c++ class, we are still only using basic functions, so the professor suggested reading in the ISBN and storing it under a char variable.

```
**#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()*
{
 int Counter;
 int WeightedSum;

char ISBN[11] = { 0 };
char Choice;
char Again{};
int Sum = 0;
const char X = 10;
int IterationCounter = 0;

do // begininng of do/while loop
{
    cout << "Would you like to check if your ISBN is valid or not? ";
    cout << "Press Y/y for yes or N/n for no and to end program: ";
    cin >> Choice; //choice input
    cout << endl << endl; // blank line 
    while (Choice != 'Y' && Choice != 'y' && Choice != 'N' && Choice != 'n') // beginning of while loop. checks user input to see if valid y/n choice
    {
        cout << "Invalid choice! Enter either Y/y or N/n"; // displays when anything other than y/n is entered 
        cout << "Press Y/y for yes or N/n for no and to end program: "; //gives user another chance to enter y/n
        cin >> Choice;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    if (Choice == 'Y' || Choice == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter the ISBN you wish to convert: " << endl;
        cin >> ISBN;
        cout << ISBN;
        cout << endl << endl;
        for (Counter = 0; Counter < 10; Counter++)
        {
            WeightedSum = ISBN[10] * (10 - Counter);
            Sum = WeightedSum + Sum;
        }
        cout << Sum;
        if (Sum % 11 == 0)
        {
            cout << Sum;
            cout << " Is a valid ISBN " << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << Sum;
            cout << " Is invalid " << endl;
        }*
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: "my for() statement", "the outside loops", "my formula", "the conversion" - you are aware that all of that is invisible to use, aren't you? Please show your code as a [mre]. "reading in the ISBN and storing it under a char variable" that sounds wrong, strictly interpreted you cannot store a multi-digit ISBN in a single `char` variable.

Comment: Possibly helpful to make this a good and answerable question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: For an MRE, try to copy the shown code back and compile it. If that does not work, fix the compiler errors. I am for example pretty sure that you dropped an`#include` statement or more and that the code is incomplete (at least lacking some function body definition syntax and a closing `}`.

Comment: Advice -- Instead of all of the prompts, create a simple function that takes an ISBN number and returns if it is valid, and test it with simple, maybe hardcoded input.  Once that works, then you put that in a larger program.  It looks like you spent a lot of time on input / output instead of the important part of the program.

Comment: `cin >> ISBN;` -- What if the user enters more than 11 characters?  You've now introduced a buffer overrun.  Use `std::string`, not a char array.

Comment: we currently arent on stings yet. the professor suggested reading in the ISBN as a string

Comment: There are  two  ISBN versions. ISBN-10 and ISBN-13.

Comment: If you continue to use a `char[]` array instead of a `std::string`, then to avoid a buffer overflow you should use `cin.get(ISBN, 11)` instead of `cin >> ISBN`, or at least use `cin >> setw(11) >> ISBN`.  But note that these take null terminators into account, so you should change 11 to 12 (or 14 if you want to to support ISBN-13), even in the declaration of `ISBN`.

Comment: What does the `*` after that last `else` do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
WeightedSum = ISBN[10] * (10 - Counter);
```

You're always performing math against the character at position 11. Because you multiply it by `10 - Counter`, which is 0 through 9, you're going to basically be multiplying it by the sum of 1 through 10, or 55. Since 55 is divisible by 11, you'll always end up with `if (Sum % 11 == 0)` evaluating to true. Worst case, you may even hit an access violation since you're not checking the length of `ISBN` before accessing it.

Comment: so what do you suggest I do? sorry im really new to all of this and it is becoming a lot on me. thanks for your help

Comment: @theghost What was the purpose of having the fixed `10` in `ISBN[10]` ? It's the 11:th(!) digit in the array. Isn't the checksum calculation supposed to deal with _all_ digits?

Comment: no danger of an access violation, the array is a fixed size no matter what was read into it

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sure, the 11:th digit is `'\0'` if the user entered 10 digits. Otherwise uninitiallized (and UB if read I guess), but it doesn't make sense to only take one digit into account in the checksum calculation.

Comment: The array is initialised to `0`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah, I see that now. Ok, still, just counting one digit - that the user didn't even enter doesn't make sense.

Comment: Never said there was anything wrong with the rest of your answer, just that you wouldn't get an access violation

Comment: @AlanBirtles I wasn't even thinking about access violations. I was thinking about it being the 11:th digit when the user was asked to enter 10. :-)